# Powershell Publish-Module to Powershell Gallery fails after creating Nuget Package

Tags: powershell, module, nuget, gallery, publish

I am trying to publish a new version of a [Powershell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Nuttercode-PRTG/1.3) to the [Powershell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/manage/upload) by using

```
Publish-Module -Name "Nuttercode-PRTG" -NuGetApiKey $apiKey -Verbose -RequiredVersion 1.4
```

The module .psm1 and .psd1 files can be found [here](https://github.com/johanneslatzel/powershellmodules/tree/master/Nuttercode-PRTG/1.4).

After dotnet.exe created the package in {myUserDir}\AppData\Local\Temp\{random numbers}\Nuttercode-PRTG it reports:

```
VERBOSE: finished running C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe with exit code 0
VERBOSE: Created Nuget Package
VERBOSE: Successfully created nuget package at
Write-Error: Failed to publish module 'Nuttercode-PRTG': 'Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NupkgPath' because it is an empty string.'.
```

Afterwards the temp-folder gets deleted. To me this sounds like an internal problem of Publish-Module or dotnet.exe, but I have no idea what is going on or if I am doing something very wrong myself. I also created a new api key just in case but it did not affect the result.

I am using Windows 10 20H2 (Build 19042.1469), Powershell 7.2.2, PowerShellGet 2.2.5, and dotnet.exe 6.0.201. I am able to replicate the problem on another computer using the same command and arguments using Windows 11 21H2 (Build 22000.556), Powershell 7.2.1, PowershellGet 2.2.5, and dotnet.exe 5.0.102.